# Best way to combine multiple Flux<T> into Flux<T[]>

Tags: java, project-reactor

currently, I am doing it with multiple `.zipWith()` calls.

```java
    frontLeft.getState()
        .zipWith(frontRight.getState(), (x, y) -> new SwerveModuleState[] {x, y})
        .zipWith(backLeft.getState(), (x, y) -> new SwerveModuleState[] {x[0], x[1], y})
        .zipWith(backRight.getState(), (x, y) -> new SwerveModuleState[] {x[0], x[1], x[2], y})
        .subscribe(
            states -> {
              estimator.update(
                  new Rotation2d(gyro.getYaw()), states); // new Rotation2d requires that the second arg is of type SwerveModuleState[]
            });
```

where `frontLeft.getState()`, `frontRight.getState()`, etc, is of type SwerveModuleState.
I was doing it with Flux.zip(), but I found that `states` would be of type `Object[]`

EDIT:

related github issue: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an API limitation at present since the generic type of the `Publisher`s isn't captured, so you have to work with an `Object[]` when using `Flux.zip`, for example by copying into a typed array:

```java
Flux.zip((Object[] array) -> Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, String[].class),
                frontLeft.getState(), frontRight.getState(), backLeft.getState(), backRight.getState())
        .subscribe(states -> estimator.update(new Rotation2d(gyro.getYaw()), states));
```

Answer (score 0):

what about these static methods?

Flux zip(Iterable> sources,
final Function<? super Object[], ? extends O> combinator)

Flux zip(final Function<? super Object[], ? extends O> combinator,
Publisher<? extends I>... sources)

Comment: the issue is that the `Function<>` takes `? super Object[]` as a type param. still have to cast in the `combinator`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).